# Async pipe subscription not work correctly when nested inside ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6

I have a quick search box which I would like to have a loading animation. I used `ng-template` with `ngIf` to show/hide this animation. And I have some li's nested inside the same div which subscribed to a search result Observable using async pipe to display results. This async pipe works great when there's no `*ngIf` on the parent div, but seems it is not subscribing anymore when I apply `ngIf`. Is this an expected behavior? Or am I doing anything wrong?

My markup looks like this.

```
<input #searchBox type="text" (keyup)="itemLoading=true;searchTerm$.next(searchBox.value)"/>
<div *ngIf="!itemLoading else loading">
<!--Remove ngIf then items will display correctly when search-->
<!-- <div> -->
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of result$ | async ">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
  <p>LOADING...</p>
</ng-template>
```

And I am using switchMap to run the search:

```
private source = of(['apple', 'pear', 'banana']).pipe(delay(500));

  searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();
  result$: Observable<string[]>;
  itemLoading = false;  

  constructor() {
    this.result$ = this.searchTerm$.pipe(
      tap(term => console.log('search term captured: ' + term)),
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(() => this.source.pipe(
        tap(_ => {
            console.log('source reached');
            this.itemLoading = false;
          })
      ))
    );
  }
```

When `ngIf` is present in parent div, the 'source reached' message is never logged in console, as well as the loading template keeps hanging there.

Here is a full working example of what I am talking about: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ukcqu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rewriting the `*ngIf` as hidden should solve the problem.  The reason result$ isn't working is because those elements inside the `*ngIf` won't be added to the dom until itemLoading is false.  At that point they'll subscribe to result$, but the event will have already occurred.

Alternatively `shareReplay(1)` might also do the trick without you having to rewrite anything else, as the reply will run when the Observable is subscribed too.

**Solution A**

```
<div [hidden]="itemLoading">
<!-- ... -->
</div>
<div [hidden]="!itemLoading">
  <p>LOADING...</p>
</div>
```

**Solution B**

```
this.result$ = this.searchTerm$.pipe(
  //...
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Comment: shareReplay does fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `async` pipe within your `*ngIf`.  You can find a great writeup at https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe

In short:

```html
<div *ngIf="(user$ | async) as user; else loading">
  <user-profile
    [user]="user">
  </user-profile>
  <user-messages
    [user]="user">
  </user-messages>
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
  Loading stuff...
</ng-template>
```

If this does not work for you, another cleaner solution (IMO) is to use 
 [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject).  When your dom gets around to subscribing, it will get the last observable data.

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it in Angular. Using `ng-template`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to add everything into your DOM, you can group your observables using `forkJoin` ([RxJS doc](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)) operator. Then you can keep your syntax with `*ngIf` and the DOM will stay clean.

**Solution C**

.ts

```
this.data$ = forkjoin([yourObs1, yourObs2,...]).pipe(
switchMap(myResolvedArray=>{
// Here you must return the object you want
return {
dataObs1: myResolvedArray[0]
...
}
})
)
```

.html

```
<div *ngIf='data$|async as data'>
//data.dataObs1 is accessible like other attributes
</div>
```